# Create ul list in Custom Meta Box?

Tags: custom-field

I need to create an ul list in a Custom Meta Box.

The content/text area of the post is already taken up with other information.

Is it possible to create another text area like WP built in one so I could us the Unordered list button.

-- EDIT --

I'm not sure how else I can describe this.

I know how to create Custom Meta Boxes. I can create text input fields and textarea fields.

I would like a Custom Meta Box that would output the information in it as an Unordered list on the site.

In WP's textarea in a post I can type text, select it then press the unordered list button to make it into an unordered list.

How can I do this with a Custom Meta Box?

Comment: For me, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you explain this in terms of code?

Answer (score 5):

You can add your information in regular metabox textarea and separate prospective list items with new line. Then just format it as list in your template:

```
<?php
$list_items = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_custom_field_name', true);
     if($list_items){
        $list_items = explode("\n", $list_items)
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($list_items as $list_item) {
                    echo '<li>' . $list_item . '</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Or you can add one more TinyMCE editor (like the one for post text) as described here: [Custom fields or something else](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/custom-fields-or-something-else/83965#83965)

Answer (score 0):

You can create "Custom Fields" that allow you to add additional information to your post, stored as "post meta".

There are lot of good plugins available to help with this. I suggest you try "Advanced Custom Fields" (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

-- Updated --

In response to your added details, you have a few options.

You can add another Visual Editor (using a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields) which would let you use the ordered list tool.

You could also write your content as HTML, using the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags accordingly.

Last but not least, though more complex, you can pass your values in as comma separated and then loop through them in the template.

Comment: I tried writing the content as HTML but after I save/publish it the html is removed

Comment: How are you creating the meta boxes? My guess is that the plugin or method you're using is stripping the HTML out.

Comment: By default html tags are not removed.