# Wrap Meta Box with <li> and </li> for each new line

Tags: list, line-breaks

I'm trying to automate one of our posting aspects. We post a lot of lyrics and have a system of meta boxes which we use to input various pieces of information about each set of lyrics we post. One aspect that is a little annoying is having to search & replace `<li>`<`/li>`tags to the start and end of each new line of lyrics. I was hoping to have PHP echo this automatically but my code is not working at the moment.
Here is my untouched code which outputs a verse of lyrics (we use `wpautop`so that line breaks are respected):

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_lyrics_1', true) ) : ?>
<?php $lyrics_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_lyrics_1', true) ?>
<ul>
<?php echo wpautop( $lyrics_1) ; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is my attempt at outputting `<li>`tags, which didn't work. :(

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_lyrics_1', true) ) : ?>
<?php $lyrics_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_lyrics_1', true) ?>
<ul>
<?php 
echo "<li>\n"; wpautop( $lyrics_1) ; "</li>\n"; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is in `$lyrics_1`? is this multiple lines?

Comment: See my answer to the identical question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84815/11761

Comment: @MaxYudin. I could not get that to work - returned error unexpected { .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<li>
    <?php echo wpautop( $lyrics_1);?>
</li>
```

instead of this line:

```
<?php echo "<li>\n"; wpautop( $lyrics_1) ; "</li>\n"; ?>
```

**edit**: thanks @Toscho for the syntax edit, I made a hasty error in my earlier revision ;-)

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately - it was the first thing I tried. It returns like this:
    <ul>
    <li><p>Hi<br/>
    Ok<br/>
    Let's go<br/>
    Fo sho</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
It doesn't apply the `<li>`to each line, rather before and after each block of lyrics.

Comment: do you want to have each p block within li tag, like: <li><p>...</p></li> ?

Comment: if so you can try: <?php echo str_replace(array('<p>','</p>'),array('<li><p>','</p></li>'),wpautop( $lyrics_1));?>

Comment: This won't work unfortunately. `wpautop` adds `<br />` tags to mark the line end. I changed your search value `</p>`for `<br />`and tried `\n`in place of `<p>`but to no avail. I got the text returned as one long `<li>`item!

Comment: so you want to change: `<ul> <p>Hi<br/> Ok<br/> Let's go<br/> Fo sho</p> </ul>` into this: `<ul> <li>Hi</li> <li>Ok</li> <li>Let's go</li> <li>Fo sho </li> </ul>` ?