# Output list from each line of metabox (shortcode)

Tags: metabox, list

Hey I have a textarea in my metabox and I display the info using a shortcode.
I want to output the data from that metabox as a list (each line is a list item).
I used the code from  [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84806/create-ul-list-in-custom-meta-box) but changed it a little, because it gave me a parse/syntax error.

I need the arrays to be inside a specific div and p class, and without the explode and the code they display well (writing the html tags inside the metabox - which I don't want to do, I want just the lines of text to result the list)

My code for the shortcode is:

```
add_shortcode('cv', 'vp_cv');
function vp_cv($atts, $content=null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'number' => 6
), $atts));
    $content = filter_shortcode($content);
global $post;
$output .= '<div class="container">';
$query = new WP_Query('post_type=resume&posts_per_page=' . $number . '&cat=' . $categories);
while($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $projects = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resume_projects', true);
 if($projects){
    $projects = explode("\n", $projects);} 
        ?>
         <ol>
         <?php for($i = 0;
         $i<sizeof($project);
         $i++){ ?>
         <li> <?php echo $project[$i]; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ol>
```

The output is:

```
<?php
    
$output .= '<div class="one-third">';

$output .= '<p class="cv-title">' . $title . '</p>';
    $output .= '<p class="cv-projects">'  . $projects . '</p></div>';       
endwhile;
    $output .= '</div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>';
return $output;
}
```

The title displays ok but the $projects gives me literally "Array".

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed $output in "for" loop, wrong $project(s) name.

```
add_shortcode( 'cv', 'vp_cv' );
function vp_cv( $atts, $content = null ) {

    //.....

    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $title = get_the_title();
        $projects = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'resume_projects', true);

        if( $projects ) $projects = explode("\n", $projects); 

        $output .= '<p class="cv-title">' . $title . '</p>';
        $output .= '<p class="cv-projects">';
        $output .= '<ol>';

        for( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $projects ); $i++ ) {
            $output .= '<li>' . $projects[$i] .'</li>';
        }

        $output .= "</ol>";
        $output .= "</p>";

    //.....

    return $output;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great!! yeah it helps :) cant give you "useful answer" because of my low reputation for being a noobie heh.

Comment: you're welcome, never give up : )

Comment: Now i can give you points so I came back to do so.